# Regex to discard exceeding input while allowing optional digits and partial match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a regex to implement these features:

1. Allow an optional digit;
2. Discard part of input that exceeds desired length;
3. If there isn't a full match, allow partial matches.

**UPDATE**:

4. Know when there's only a partial match, or a complete match (it would be complete when all required digits are present)

Currently I'm handling this 4th requirement counting optional digits in pattern, but unfortunately this is out of place (handled in consumer code instead of service code)

**END OF UPDATE**

I have the following input and desired output:

```
+-------+--------+
| input | output |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | 1      |
+-------+--------+
| 12    | 12     |
+-------+--------+
| 123   | 123    |
+-------+--------+
| 1234  | 123    |
+-------+--------+
```

I have designed this generic regex:

```
^(\d*?)(\d?)(\d?).*?$
```

For every input, however, I got `12`.

How should I change it to have the desired output?

Sample: https://www.regex101.com/r/vS3bH3/1

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
\b(\d{1,3})
```

`\b` makes sure we have a new digit (after a word boundary), and we match from 1 to 3 digits (matching is greedy to return as many digits as we encounter.)

See [updated demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vS3bH3/2)

Matches:

```
1    -- > 1
12   -- > 12
123  -- > 123
1234 -- > 123
```

Or, elaborating your regex further, here is what I cann suggest:

```
^(\d?)(\d?)(\d?).*?$
```

See [demo here](https://www.regex101.com/r/vS3bH3/3)

Mind that `*?` will prevent that capturing group from matching in favor of the next same pattern without `*`. So, removing `*`s we can guarantee the digits appear in Groups 1, 2, 3.

**EDIT**:

To differentiate between a full and partial match, you can use an alternation list with capturing groups.

```
\b(\d{1,3})\b|\b(\d{1,3})
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vS3bH3/4)

If Group 1 is not empty, we have a full match, if Group 2 is not empty, the match is partial.

Comment: The problem is related to the last part `.*?`. I believe I need to distinguish between optional and required symbols, so I've just though I could be able to have 2 different regexes, instead of only one.

Comment: Also, I've updated question with a 4th requirement to narrow down possible solutions. Thanks for your input, it has made me look better at the problem.

Comment: @Werlang: Please check my edit, I guess using capturing groups is a good way to check what kind of match we are having.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a regular expression is more difficult than another solution:

```
function toFixedInt(num, dig){
  return parseInt(num.toString().split('').slice(0, dig).join(''));
}
var threeDigits = toFixedInt(1234567, 3);
```